# $C^m\to C^{m-1}$ projection map projecting out last factor inducing $G_n(C^{m-1})\to G_n(C^m)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, k-theory, grassmannian, topological-k-theory

Assume $m>n$. Consider projection map $\pi: C^m\to C^{m-1}$ by $(z_1,\dots, z_m)\to (z_1,\dots, z_{m-1})$. Let $G_n(V)$ be the set of codimension $n$ hyperplanes of $V$ and endow the topology as a subspace of projective space.

"This map induces the following continuous map $G_n(C^{m-1})\to G_n(C^m)$."

$\textbf{Q:}$ How so? I do not see why projection should induce such an obvious map. There is embedding $C^{m-1}\subset C^m$ by setting $z_m=0$. Then I have $G_n(C^{m-1})\to G_n(C^m)$ induced by this inclusion map by sending wedge product to wedge products where I have identified the image in the corresponding projective spaces.

Ref. Atiyah, K-theory Chpt 1 pg 28.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $e_m=(0,\cdots,0,1)\in \mathbb C^m$, the required map is  $$G_n(\mathbb C^{m-1})\to G_n(\mathbb C^m):L\mapsto L\oplus \mathbb Ce_m=\pi^{-1}(L)$$

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question. It seems that if the book requires dimension $n$ hyperplane instead of codimension $n$, then the map is induced by inclusion(adopted in Milnor's Characteristic Classes, Chpt 6) but for codimension $n$(adopted in Atiyah, K-theory), the map is induced by projection. Was this merely a choice of convention?

Comment: This is certainly not a dumb question. No, it is not merely a choice of convention: there are many instances where we study push forward and pull back: from elementary differential geometry (immersions versus submersions) to algebraic topology (homology versus cohomology) and algebraic geometry (Chow groups can  be pushed forward, whereas  Chow rings can be pulled back). There are very interesting relations between these two processes which go under the name ["projection formulas"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67228/where-do-all-these-projection-formulas-come-from).

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for clarifications.